# -webkit-overflow-scroll:touch vertical scrolling only

Tags: html, iframe, viewport, meta

I’m getting a slightly different problem.

I've got:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

As soon as I turn on:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Then all of a sudden horizontal scrolling works, which isn't what I want. Any idea?

Thanks